# Apply CsvHelper custom converter to all string properties of a set of classes

Tags: c#, reflection, csvhelper

I'm using Josh Close's excellent CsvHelper library to read csv files and load them into a database using entity framework. This all works well except for one thing; CsvReader stores an empty string in the csv file as an empty string in the database and I would like this to be a NULL value instead. So what I've done is create a custom converter that takes care of this:

```
public class NullStringConverter : StringConverter
{
    public override object ConvertFromString(TypeConverterOptions options, string text)
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(text))
            return null;
        else
            return base.ConvertFromString(options, text);
    }
}
```

I can apply this to a string property by using a either fluent map syntax or via an attribute and it will now insert a NULL instead of an empty string.

Since I have quite a few classes containing a number of string attributes I would like to avoid having to create Map statements for each and everyone of them. I created a generic Map class that enumerates all properties and applies the custom converter to all string properties. Here's what I have sofar

```
public class DefaultStringMap<TEntity> : CsvClassMap<TEntity> where TEntity : AbstractAmtSourceEntity
{
    public DefaultStringMap()
    {
        typeof(TEntity).GetProperties()
            .Where(p => p.PropertyType == typeof(string))
            .ToList()
            .ForEach(p => Map(m => p.Name).TypeConverter<NullStringConverter>());
    }
}
```

Here `AbstractAmtSourceEntity` is my base class for all my entity classes. Here's my reader class that actually gets the data:

`public static void Read<TEntity>(TextReader reader, AmtSourceModel context) where TEntity : AbstractAmtSourceEntity
        {
            using (var csvReader = new CsvReader(reader))
            {
                csvReader.Configuration.WillThrowOnMissingField = false;
                csvReader.Configuration.Delimiter = "|";
                csvReader.Configuration.SkipEmptyRecords = true;
                 csvReader.Configuration.RegisterClassMap<DefaultStringMap<Entity1>>();
csvReader.Configuration.RegisterClassMap<DefaultStringMap<Entity2>>();
etc...
                csvReader.Configuration.IgnoreReadingExceptions = true;
                csvReader.Configuration.ReadingExceptionCallback = (ex, row) =>
                {
                    _log.Warn($"Exception caught reading row {row}", ex);
                    _log.Debug($"Exception detail: {ex.Data["CsvHelper"]}");
                };
                var records = csvReader.GetRecords<TEntity>();
                context.Set<TEntity>().AddRange(records);
                context.SaveChanges();
            }
        }`

 This doesn't work however, the mapping is not applied, so obviously I'm missing something. Can anyone tell me what's missing here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can set converters globally.

```
TypeConverterFactory.AddConverter( typeof( string ), new NullStringConverter() );
// or
TypeConverterFactory.AddConverter<string>( new NullStringConverter() );
```

Comment: Super, that's what I was looking for.

Comment: The global override to the StringConverter does not work for me in the latest version (2.16.3).  Works fine if I specify the converter explicitly as mentioned in the question.

Comment: Note that as of version 3.0, `TypeConverterFactory` is now called `TypeConverterCache` and is accessed from your instance of `CsvReader` e.g. `reader.Configuration.TypeConverterCache`. [Reference](https://github.com/JoshClose/CsvHelper/blob/04c764551c2d371e79edf162a543c3140316c48c/docs-src/src/pages/change-log.md#300)